# Bing News Search API v7, incorrect thumbnail sizes

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-search

The Bing News Search API provides thumbnail images, including a width and height. However, the width and height do not match the linked image. All of the thumbnails seem to be 100x100, but the sizes returned with the metadata are different.

You can see this in the demo App, here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-news-search-api/

For example, pulling one thumbnail entry out:

```
"thumbnail": {
  "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.7B00F1FD60C64A55968699C36FAF0FF0&pid=News",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 393
}
```

The image located at the `contentUrl` is 100x100. Makes sense to me if thumbnails are all 100x100, but where is the image that is supposed to be 480x393 (in this case)?

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference

There is a parameter `originalImg`.  If true, the original image is included in addition to the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks, originalImg flag is giving proper thumbnail image in response